# NSURLSession Redirection handler different behaviour on WatchOS

Tags: ios, watchkit, nsurlsession

I am working on updating an old WatchOS app to support WatchOS 4.0. The app makes some network requests, one of which responds with a 302 redirect status code and corresponding Location header. I do not want to follow the redirection, and the 302 response headers contains all the info I need for this particular request.

I am using `NSURLSession` and have implemented the delegate method `- URLSession:task:willPerformHTTPRedirection:newRequest:completionHandler:`.

The delegate method is called as expected, and inside it I call `completionHandler(nil)` to tell the OS not to follow the redirect. All is fine up to this point.

The `NSURLSessionTask` completion handler at this point typically gets called immediately after this with a request cancelled error, and that's fine too.

Here's the strange part. When the Apple Watch is paired with an iPhone, I get the behaviour described above. However when I put the iPhone into Aeroplane Mode to simulate the Watch being out of range, with the network requests being made directly over wifi or cellular, I get a different behaviour.

The redirection delegate method is still called, as expected, however the `NSURLSessionTask` completion handler does not get called immediately. Rather, it gets called some time later with a -1001 Request Timed Out error.

```
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration] delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];

NSURLSessionTask *task = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    // Odd behaviour described above here
}];

[task resume];
```

The delegate redirection method:

```
- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session task:(NSURLSessionTask *)task willPerformHTTPRedirection:(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response newRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLRequest * _Nullable))completionHandler {
    completionHandler(nil);
}
```

This has been frustratingly difficult to debug to this point as I cannot debug through Xcode and have not been able to find a way to proxy the watch network requests.

Has anyone experienced this behaviour, or have any clues on why it's behaving differently? Is this a WatchOS defect?